# How can I make sure that all JSON schemas in my project are valid?

Tags: javascript, validation, jsonschema

I have many json schemas in separate `*.json` files.

How can I easily check that they are both valid JSON and valid [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html)?

I prefer solutions in Javascript, because I'd like to add this step in my `npm test` procedure, but actually any CLI tool would do.

I was thinking that maybe, since JSON schema is JSON, I could validate my JSON schemas using some "JSON meta schema", but I couldn't find anything like this.

NOTE: I'm **not** asking how to validate a JSON using a JSON schema. And I'm not really asking how to check that a file is just a valid JSON. I ask how to validate the schema, that it is **both valid JSON and valid [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html)**.

Comment: There's a Grunt [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-jsonlint).

Comment: JSHint isn't going to help in this case. It's for validating JS which is something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Meta-schema here:

http://json-schema.org/documentation.html

With it, my question boils down to validating a JSON using a JSON schema, which is easy (see validators [here](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html)).

Answer (score -1):

Using npm:

```
npm install jshint -g
cd my_json_folder/
jshint .
```

Also check out https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint

Comment: JSHint isn't going to help in this case. It's for validating JS which is something completely different.

Answer (score -2):

There are many sites available...

I use [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) site frequently for json format.

VoteUp if it helps

Comment: This does not answer the question. I wanted to validate JSON schema correctness.